# ASP_0177_:_800401f3|Server.CreateObject_Failed error while migrating Classic asp from iis 6 to iis 7.5

Tags: asp-classic, iis-7

While migrating a Classic asp project from windows server 2003(IIS 6) to windows server 2008 R2(IIS 7.5), the Menu is not getting loaded, when checked in the log. It displays the below error.

`Menu.asp |107|ASP_0177_:_800401f3|Server.CreateObject_Failed`

When checked the code, the line shows

`Server.CreateObject("webCalendarv1.objCalandar")`

Can some one please help me why im getting this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Server.CreateObject_Failed

This type of error usually means the component (DLL) you are trying to reference isn't installed on that server or your syntax is incorrect.

As you say that you've moved servers I would suggest that you check that the

> webCalendarv1.objCalandar

component is installed/registered on your new server. Most likely you can move the relevant DLL file across and run;

```
Regsvr32.exe nameofthecomponent.dll
```

One thing you'll have to check is that you have the correct bit version of your component that matchs the bit version of your Windows Server OS. There is an option within IIS that allows use of 32bit components on a 64bit Windows Server for a specific App Pool.